# PHP buffer ob_flush() vs. flush()

Tags: php, flush, output-buffering

What's the difference between `ob_flush()` and `flush()` and why must I call both?

The [`ob_flush()` reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) says:

> This function will send the contents of the output buffer (if any).

The [`flush()` reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) says:

> Flushes the write buffers of PHP and whatever backend PHP is using (CGI, a web server, etc).

However, it continues to say:

> [it] may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web server…

So, seems to me that I could just use `ob_flush()` all of the time. However, I get strange results when I do that.  Could someone explain in simple terms what's going on here?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`ob_flush` sends an application-initiated buffer. There may be multiple nested `ob_start()`'s in any PHP script. `ob_flush` passes the current content to the upper layer.

PHP itself might (at its own discretion) buffer output. This depends on the back-end. But usually `FastCGI` has a socket buffer on its own. Therefore `flush()` needs to be invoked as well to send the current content to the web server.

And now the web server might itself implement another buffering scheme (`mod_deflate` or content filter), which you have no influence over. But this is seldom, as it needs to be configured specifically.

Anyway, use both.

Comment: Use ob_flush and flush and use them in that order.

Comment: The important detail missing from this answer is the [`output_buffering`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) configuration option, whose default value in production versions of php.ini is 4096. That means that when any PHP script starts, the first 4096 bytes of output get buffered (in a buffer flushable with `ob_flush()`). This is why it is necessary to use `ob_flush()` as well as `flush()`. Disabling `output_buffering` via php.ini or calling `ob_end_clean()` or `ob_end_flush()` at the start of the script removes this necessity.

Comment: Thanks @MarkAmery, but `ob_end_clean()` at the "start of the script" seems counter-intuitive. You mean we should include this soon after `ob_start()` and before the two flushes?

Comment: Well I have an `ob_start()` and an `ob_end_clean()` at the very start of the script. Then after any "echo" during the script, I also include `ob_flush(); flush();`, and I expect that while the script is taking time, whatever has been done thus far will be output on the screen (in the browser). But nothing is out put until the very end. What am I missing?

Comment: @KhomNazid A browser observation is not the same as debugging the HTTP stream. Incremental and delayed output to an incomplete HTML DOM is not likely to be visible. Do some CLI testing with your current setup. (And then, and only then, start a different question about it.)

Comment: Thanks @mario. I am only looking for browser observation. Are `ob_..()` functions not the right ones?

Answer (score 35):

`ob_flush` flushes output buffers *you* created with a function like `ob_start`

`flush` flushes buffered output of the PHP script itself to its caller

Answer (score 26):

`ob_flush()` is a high-level flush. It flushes high-level buffers and puts all content in the low-level, internal buffers ready to send.

- Note that the `ob_` family of functions create *stacks* of buffers, so just blindly writing `ob_flush()` everywhere is indeed going to give you "strange results" if the code was written to take advantage of this stacking.

`flush()` is a low-level flush, instructing PHP to flush its internal, low-level data buffers.

Below that still, there will be socket-layer buffers; below that, there are network-layer buffers. And, at the lowest level, the queue of electrons going down the data cable.

Comment: Well I have an `ob_start()` and an `ob_end_clean()` at the very start of the script. Then after any "echo" during the script, I also include `ob_flush(); flush();`, and I expect that while the script is taking time, whatever has been done thus far will be output on the screen (in the browser). But nothing is out put until the very end. What am I missing?

Comment: @KhomNazid Buffering by intermediate stages, like the webserver, proxies, your browser...

Answer (score 12):

I guess this is in relation to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191349/php-buffer-why-r-n). The significant advantage of using output buffering is when it's used alongside data compression. If you're not using `ob_gzhandler`, there's little to gain. `flush` alone will just commit whatever output data is still on the server. With `ob_start` and its counterparts `ob_flush`, `ob_end_clean` and `ob_end_flush`, whatever is waiting to be compressed (look at `flush` and `ob_flush` as referring to different buckets - `ob` sends data to `flush`, `flush` sends data to browser - may not be accurate but that's the idea) will be wrapped up and sent to the client.

Comment: Thanks, the bucket analogy is a nice example.