# php flush(); not writing anything to page

Tags: php

I'm running a large scraper script and I have some `echo "$this is happening"` calls set up ont he page to help me do debugging.

I'd like these messages to show up as they're written, rather than at the end of the 20-minute scrape because, obviously, if things go wrong I don't want to wait so long to know about them.

I've tried setting `output_buffering = off` in `php.ini`, as well as `implicit_flush = on`. In my script, I've put `flush();` after every `echo` call, but to no avail.

What's the correct way to do this? When I load the script it's currently going to an invisible page (that is, my php script's tab shows whatever was on the last tab that I was looking at in Chrome). Nothing is being written.

If it helps I'm running WAMP / Apache on Win7 64bit.

Comment: Hard to say what is happening without seeing code examples.

Comment: Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/0Z9zWSPL Standard disclaimer, I have permission to scrape this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ob_flush()` (https://www.php.net/ob_flush) before calling `flush()`. See discussion [here](https://www.php.net/flush) and [PHP buffer ob_flush() vs. flush()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191385/php-buffer-ob-flush-vs-flush).

Comment: Are you suggesting I replace all of my `flush()`s with `ob_flush()`, or somehow use them together? Isn't the whole point of `implicit_flush = on` to do what `ob_flush()` does?

Comment: Done, still getting the same (lack of) output. See the pastebin above, I've replaced every `flush()` with `ob_flush(); flush();` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for more of a logging feature. See [error_log()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) and then find a [windows tailing](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/wintail/) application to monitor the log file.