# PHP output buffering issues

Tags: php, output, buffering

since two days i'm trying to stop the buffer on my server, i disabled the `output_buffering` in `php.ini` i checked it was disabled  with `phpinfo()`.

Under xampp(Localhost) it works like a charm, same testing code(below), the code runs without waiting for everything to be finished, no buffer, a dream =)

On my server the `output_buffering` show me `No value` in `phpinfo()` so i think it's disabled, but still it's not workingn i need to wait until the loop finish his work, anyway to make this work like on my xampp config ? thanks !

testing code here :

```
for($i=1; $i<=5000; $i++){
    echo $i."<br>";

    flush();
    usleep(1000);
}
```

ps : i tested with php 5.6 & php7 on Debian and Ubuntu, my xampp is naturally running on windows(10)

Comment: if you want this kind of browser interaction you should use client side code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flush output after each \`echo\` call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133209/how-to-flush-output-after-each-echo-call). Check out the second answer which appears to solve it by sending out a content-type header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ob_flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) *and* flush()

What's the difference you may ask? [That's a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191385/php-buffer-ob-flush-vs-flush)

Comment: thanks, i just tried but still won't work :( it wait to finish before allow me to see the output

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers don't display anything until the body of the response contains a certain amount of data (about 1024 bytes). The following may look a bit hacky - but like this it works as expected:

```
<?php
echo '<!-- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -->';
flush();
for($i=1; $i<=5000; $i++) {
  echo $i."<br>";
  flush();
  usleep(1000);
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, it still wont work :(  i can't figure why, working like a charm on xampp