# PHP output buffering on XAMPP

Tags: php, buffer

It seems that despite everything i've done trying to get it to work, It just doesnt work.

Here's what all I did :

1. output_buffering = 4096
2. zlib.output_compression = Off
3. Tried using **ob_implicit_flush();**
4. Tried using **ob_flush();**
5. Reduced the buffer size in the ini setting **output_buffering** to **1**

Following is the code that i'm trying to get to work (basically output a line every 1 second) but i'm getting the entire output after 15 seconds.

With **ob_implicit_flush()** :

```
<?php
ob_implicit_flush();

for($i=0;$i<=15;$i++)
{
    print($i."<BR />");
    sleep(1);
}
```

with using **ob_start()** and **ob_flush()** methods :

```
<?php
ob_start();
for($i=0;$i<=15;$i++)
{
    print($i."<BR />");
    ob_flush();
}
```

Is there any other PHP setting that I am missing ? Please help.

EDIT : Using the example by the OP in this SO question, it works : [PHP buffer why \r\n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191349/php-buffer-why-r-n)

I see that I had to do a str_repeat() to generate a string to overflow the buffer. Why is nothing of this mentioned in the php manual ? Is this really the procedure ?

Comment: This code looks incomplete. I cannot see the calls to the `ob_`* set of functions in the context of the samples.

Comment: sorry about that, i've updated it now.

Answer (score 1):

PHP returns one response to a request. If you have `sleep()` calls in that code then the whole response will wait for those calls. PHP doesn't pass a response back to the browser in chunks even if you put a one second sleep in between `print`s.

If you are using PHP as an interactive console then this could should work and behave as you are anticipating.

Answer (score 0):

Read http://www.php.net/flush description, it can help you to understand what happens.