# How do echo out progress on MAMP using flush()

Tags: php, echo, mamp, progress, flush

I'm trying to run a simple PHP script on MAMP. I'm using PHP 5.2.17 and I have compression turned off. Im trying to execute this simple script

```
<?php
    ob_flush();
    foreach(range(1,9) as $n){
    echo $n."\n";
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

For sme reason this is not doing what it is supposed to. Rather than sequentially echoing out the numbers, it's simply echoing them out when the loop is done. Am I missing something? is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Output buffering is a mechanism for controlling how much output data
> (excluding headers and cookies) PHP should keep internally before
> pushing that  data to the client. If your application's output exceeds
> this setting, PHP  will send that data in chunks of roughly the size
> you specify.  Turning on this setting and managing its maximum buffer
> size can yield some  interesting side-effects depending on your
> application and web server.  You may be able to send headers and
> cookies after you've already sent output  through print or echo. You
> also may see performance benefits if your server is  emitting less
> packets due to buffered output versus PHP streaming the output  as it
> gets it. On production servers, 4096 bytes is a good setting for
> performance  reasons.

**Note: Output buffering can also be controlled via Output Buffering Control
functions.**

**php.ini Possible Values:**

```
On = Enabled and buffer is unlimited. (Use with caution) 
Off = Disabled    
Integer = Enables the buffer and sets its maximum size in bytes.  
eg: output_buffering = Off
```

**Note: This directive is hardcoded to Off for the CLI SAPI**

http://php.net/output-buffering

A Working example if output_buffering is set to 4096

```
<?php
ob_start();
// Output string to overflow browser php.ini output_buffering setting.
echo str_repeat(PHP_EOL, 4097);

for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
  echo PHP_EOL.$i;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(1);
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it is the buffer size

[PHP buffer why \r\n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191349/php-buffer-why-r-n)

This example worked for me